# The max arc length for 3 symmetrical circles to intersect

Tags: geometry

Consider the following:

[image]

3 Identical circles, intersecting in a way so that all 3 arc lengths outside are the same length.

Now here is a similar situation:

[image]

The arc length for the circles got bigger, but it is still equal on all side and symmetrical, also the circles are the same size.

Again, L1=L2=L3, R1=R2=R3.

Is there a way to keep going like this, until it is no longer possible to have a symmetrical situation like this. What would the max arc length be, in terms of the radius ? Hope I was clear!

Thanks all

P.S: Excuse my drawings, It may not be exactly as I described, I would gladly accept any software idea to better draw geometrical figures.

Comment: I doubt that the arc lengths are equal in the second image...

Comment: @johannesvalks Yes, I am using Dr. Geo to draw the shapes and I find it hard to draw symmetrical so I did as best I could. Any idea for a better software to use? Either way, assume they are indeed the same arc length.

Comment: when the three arc lengths are equal and the circels have the same radius then the intersection points form an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write “symmetrical”, what you mean is mirror symmetry, right?

Let's for the moment assume all radii are $R=1$ and the centers of the circles are located at $(a,0)$, $(-a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ for some $a,b>0$. That ensures the symmetry, so now you have to formulate the condition for equal arc length.

I did that using some lengthy computation: formulated points with variables as conditions, then formulated all on-circle conditions as polynomial equations. I also formulated the equal-arclength condition as a polynomial equation, and I did so once using the determinant (which scales with the sine of the angle) and once using the dot product (which scales with the cosine). I used variable elimination techniques to obtain a relation between $a$ and $b$, and factorized that. Lastly I looked for factors common to both equal-angle formulations, and among those chose the only one which makes sense for intersecting circles, which turns out to be $3a^2=b^2$.

Perhaps there are easier ways to obtain this. After all, all that this condition tells you is the fact that the centers of the circles *have to be* arranged such that they form a isosceles triangle. Using this condition, you can move freely between the “all circles equal” and the “two circles just touch in one point” extremes:

[image: Animation]

I did the above animation with sage, but for interactive geometry construction I'd suggest [Cinderella](http://www.cinderella.de/).

The maximal arc length can be obtained from the merely-touching situation. In that case, the circle centers form an equilateral triangle and the touching points are on the edges of that triangle, with $\frac13\pi$ interior angle and $\frac53\pi$ exterior angle. So the maximal arc length is

$$L=\frac53\pi R$$

Comment: Thanks, you are great man!